# Installing Trac with Subversion 1.6

Tags: python, svn, installation, trac

I'm trying to set up Trac on my server and have successfully installed it, compiled the bytecode and run the tracd server. The only problem is that it's not reading my SVN repository.

The error I'm receiving is:

> Warning: Can't synchronize with the repository (Couldn't open Subversion repository /data1/repos: SubversionException: ("Expected FS format '2'; found format '4'", 160043)). Look in the Trac log for more information.

<sub>*(Yes, my single repository is in a folder called "repos" - I didn't set that bit up)*</sub>

The `trac.ini` looks like this:

```
repository_dir = /data1/repos
repository_type = svn
```

I'm running: Trac 0.11.5, Python 2.4.3, Collabnet SVN 1.6.5, SWIG 1.3.29

Answer (score 3):

Is your python svn library updated?  Sounds like it's stale.

Answer (score 3):

you should make sure the python binding match your SVN version.

to get the binding you can use the SVN source and compile the wrapper, the [install](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/subversion/bindings/swig/INSTALL) give an overview of the process how to build that binding.

first you would have to download the svn [source](http://subversion.tigris.org/downloads/subversion-1.6.6.tar.bz2)

BUILDING SWIG BINDINGS FOR SVN ON UNIX

after build the swig binding

> Step 1:  Install a suitable version of
>   SWIG (which is
>            currently swig version 1.3.24 - 1.3.31).
>
> ```
> * Perhaps your distribution packages a suitable version - if it
> ```
>
> does
>         install it, and skip to the last bullet point in this section.
>
> ```
> * Go to http://www.swig.org/, download the source tarball, and
> ```
>
> unpack.
>
> ```
> * In the SWIG-1.3.xx directory, run ./configure.
>
>     If you plan to build the Python bindings, and have a system
>     with more than one version of Python installed, you may need
>     to pass
>
>          --with-python=/path/to/correct/python/binary
>
>     to the configure script.  You need Python 2.4 or above.
>
>     If you plan to build the Perl bindings, and have a system
>     with more than one version of perl installed, you may need
>     to pass
>
>          --with-perl5=/path/to/correct/perl/binary
>
>     to the configure script.  You need Perl 5.8.0 or above.
>
> * Build and install.
>
>     Run 'make && make install'
>
> * To verify you have SWIG installed correctly, run "swig
> ```
>
> -version"
>         from the command line. SWIG should report that it is version
>   1.3.24
>         or newer.

and then python things

> Step 3:  Install Specific Language
>   Bindings
>
> - Python
>
>   1. Run 'make swig-py' from the top of the Subversion source tree,
>        to build the bindings.
>
>      (This will invoke SWIG on the *.i files, resulting in a collection
>        of .c source files.  It will then compile and link those .c files
>        into
>        Python libraries.)
>   2. Run 'make check-swig-py' from the top of the Subversion source
>        tree, to test the bindings
>   3. Run 'make install-swig-py' (as root, typically)
>        from the top of the Subversion source tree.  This will copy
>        your new Python libraries into the appropriate system location.
>
>      Note: If you don't have access to install to Python's site-packages
>        directory, you can have the Python modules install to your home
>        directory.  You can do this by running
>        'make install-swig-py swig_pydir=~'.
>
>      Note: If you want to install to an alternate prefix (usually only
>        if you are building packages), you can supply the prefix here.  An
>        example of doing this for building rpms looks like
>        'make install-swig-py DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT/usr'.
>   4. Make sure that whatever directory the bindings got installed
>        in
>        is in your Python search path.  That directory depends on how you
>        installed; a typical location is /usr/local/lib/svn-python/.
>
>      There are several ways to do this. See Python's documentation for
>        'sys.path' and 'PYTHONPATH'. A nice way to do this is:
>        $ echo /usr/local/lib/svn-python \
>
>      > /usr/lib/python2.x/site-packages/subversion.pth
>
>      You may also need to update your operating system's dynamic linker
>        configuration to enable Python to load these new libraries. On some
>        systems this is done by running 'ldconfig'.

Comment: ok, from what I've been reading this is most likely the problem, but what do I do from here?

Comment: @nickf: in short get the svn source of any 1.6.x and build the binding

Answer (score 2):

It may be that the Subversion Python bindings are compiled against a too-old version of Subversion, but given FS format 2 is [pre-1.0,](http://svn.collab.net/repos/svn/trunk/subversion/libsvn_repos/repos.h) it's possible something else is wrong.  You can get the Subversion client library version like this:

```
>>> import svn.client
>>> svn.client.svn_client_version().major
1
>>> svn.client.svn_client_version().minor
6
>>> svn.client.svn_client_version().patch
5
```

Comment: This shows 1.4.2 - so it looks like this is the problem, yeah? What should I do now?

Comment: @nickf: that confirm you have to update your svn python binding.

Comment: Yeah, if the CollabNet SVN version doesn't include Python bindings, you'll need to build and install from source.

Comment: @RageZ, I'm not sure what that means sorry. @Nicholas: build and install which? Subversion, Python, SWIG..?

Comment: @nickf: the binding is a lib to read the repository, python use that lib to expose an API. if the binding version doesn't match the actual repository format the API calls fail.

Comment: Build the SWIG Python bindings for Subversion.  See the other answer for more instructions, or the page on the Trac website: http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSubversion

Answer (score 0):

Looks like these guys answered your question pretty thoroughly but FYI: setup the log file so you can read it during your next problem.  In your trac.ini somewhere:

```
[logging]
log_file = trac.log
# log_format = <inherited>
log_level = DEBUG
log_type = file
```

After that, try to deploy trac to apache if possible - with mod_python or FastCGI the trac documentation says it's a lot faster than running tracd.